# Codehale metrics for Akka mailbox size of an Actor?

Tags: akka, dropwizard, metrics, gauge

I am trying to add some instrumentation to y actors and came across this 
https://github.com/kevinconaway/akka-dropwizard

This looks like it integrates with Dropwizard metrics and according to the doc, supports gauages to measure the mailbox size of actors. Is there an example on how to achieve this?

or is there any other way to see the metrics for actors using the metrics API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Akka: actor current mailbox size or number of messages awaiting processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601619/akka-actor-current-mailbox-size-or-number-of-messages-awaiting-processing)

Comment: I am interested to use gauages as the link says so I can get a view of the actor mailboxes using the Metrics API