# Is it possible to know how many messages are in an actors mailbox?

Tags: scala, akka

Is it possible to get statistics out of an actor.
Say I want to know how many messages an actor has?

I know there is a type of Router that will send messages to an actor that has the least number of messages in its mailbox.

Can I ask an actor how many messages it has?
It would be a good way to know if an actor is getting overloaded and redesign how how actor hierarchy works.

Comment: In order to achieve what you are looking for, there is the throttling that akka streams are offering. Did you think about that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Akka: actor current mailbox size or number of messages awaiting processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601619/akka-actor-current-mailbox-size-or-number-of-messages-awaiting-processing)

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution with code, but more a built-in one. If you are a licensed Lightbend user, you can leverage Lightbend Telemetry that gives you a set of Akka system internal metrics including mailbox size of actors, see https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/telemetry/current/instrumentations/akka/akka.html#actor-metrics

Comment: Yes I saw that, but was looking for a free way to do it.